# Emacs and fortran 90. In which subroutine am I?

Tags: emacsclient

I have a long file.f90 with several subroutines. Sometimes I'm editing some subroutine and I forgot where I'm (I mean the name of the subroutine that I'm editing).

I wonder what subroutine I am, I mean, where the cursor is (obviously, without move the cursor until the beginning to the subroutine to see its name). Is it possible?

Comment: does `which-function-mode` not work for you?

Comment: @rekado I assume yemino does not know that mode even exists, otherwise, he probably wouldn't have asked this question. Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: indeed @nanny (thanks for your kindness) , "which-function-mode" is exactly that I want, and I did not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could enable the global minor mode `which-function-mode`, which should be supported in `f90-mode` and `fortran-mode`.

The documentation says:

> Which Function mode is a global minor mode.  When enabled, the
>   current function name is continuously displayed in the mode line,
>   in certain major modes.

Enable it by running `M-x which-function-mode` or by adding `(which-function-mode 1)` to your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file.